# Get last directory with * in windows

Tags: cmd

```
cd $PACKAGING_EARS_PATH/target/*/*
```

but in windows `cd target/*/*` is not working.

I want to get last directory. Is it possible?

Comment: What you are asking for does not make sense.  Please elaborate. `*` is a wildcard, you cannot `cd` to a wildcard.

Comment: And what does that accomplish exactly? Again, can you provide an example? I am not a Linux developer, but I am a Windows developer.

Comment: I have 2 directory inside target folder. i want to use cd toopen it withou knowing name because they are timestamp directories

Comment: @RemyLebeau - You can CD to wildcard with Windows `cmd`. It selects the earliest sorted matching folder, even if it is hidden. `CD *\*` does not work because I believe the 2nd `*` matches the implicit `.` folder, which of course effectively does nothing. But something like `cd t*\t*` could find `test1\test2`.

Comment: @mbrc in order to do this you must know at least the first letter in the file name other wise it will not work because  if you don't know what your looking for; windows will not know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using Unix syntax to expand an environment variable. Windows uses `%var%`.

The foxidrive solution may not give the correct answer if there are deeper subdirectories.

A proper solution requires two steps.

From the command line:

```
for /d %A in ("%PACKAGING_EARS_PATH%\target\*") do @for /d %B in ("%A\*") do @cd %B
```

Using batch:

```
@echo off
for /d %%A in ("%PACKAGING_EARS_PATH%\target\*") do for /d %%B in ("%%A\*") do cd %%B
```

Windows `cmd` has an interactive command line TAB folder (and file) name completion feature that might be useful to you. For example, type `cd te` and then press the `<tab>` key and it will automatically expand to the first folder that starts with `te`. Repeatedly press `<tab>` and it will cycle through all matching folder names. You can omit leading characters and it will simply cycle through all folder names.

The TAB completion feature may or may not be enabled by default. `CMD /F:ON` will explicitly launch `cmd` with name completion enabled.

Answer (score 2):

See if this floats your boat:

```
@echo off
for /d /r "%PACKAGING_EARS_PATH%/target" %%a in (*) do set "folder=%%a"
cd "%folder%"
```

Comment: +1, But why bother with an intermediate variable. You could simply CD within the loop.

Comment: @mbrc - Even with the fix, this may not give the correct answer if `...\target\x\y\z` exists. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18594136/1012053) for a proper solution.

Comment: I've edited it to use the `/d` directory switch but it does return the deepest folder, if there are more than 2 levels.  @dbenham thanks.